# How to redraw highcharts chart?

Tags: .net, ajax, highcharts

I need help updating a (highcharts) chart in a web page after making a roundtrip to the server (where I query a database and return some json).  I am drawing a heatmap.  All works well when the page loads.  I have been unsuccessful at getting a user's selection on a dropdown to trigger another round trip and re-draw the chart.

I am unclear about where (clientside or serverside) to write code.  My code so far:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="../Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/modules/heatmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="..Cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #divHeader { height:80px; width:100%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial; font-size:18px;}
        .ddl { font-family:Tahoma, Arial; font-size:10px; font-weight:normal; color:#000; height:20px; 
            margin-bottom:1px; border:solid 1px #CCC; border-radius:2px; -moz-border-radius:2px; 
            -webkit-border-radius:2px; padding:1px; width:90px}
        .optButton { font-family: Tahoma, Arial;font-size: 10px;font-weight: normal;color: #000; }
        .thRight { text-align:right; }
        .lblParams { text-align:right; font-family:Tahoma, Arial; font-size:10px;}
        #divHeatMap { float:left; height: 300px; width: 49%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black; }
        #divResilenceMap { position: relative; float:right; margin-left: 50%; height: 300px; width: 49%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid blue; }
        #divUsage { clear: both; height: 140px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 100%; border: 1px solid green; }
        #divWorldMap { height: 300px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black; }
        #divWaterfall { height: 140px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid blue; }
        #divGoogleEarth { height: 440px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black; }
        #divDetails { float:right; position:absolute; left:150px; top:13px; background:#F7F7F9; 
            border:solid 1px #D6DBE1; color:#333; padding:5px}
        #divContent { position:relative; top:-100px; left:180px; width:90%; }
        #tabContainer { width:100%; }
        </style>
    <style>
      @import url(../Cesium/build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
      #cesiumContainer { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif; }
      html { height: 100%; }
      body { padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function refreshHeatMap()
    {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: { type: 'heatmap', marginTop: 40, marginBottom: 40 },
            title: { text: 'Surface Tokens'},
            xAxis: { categories: <%= volumes%>, title: 'Volumes' },
            yAxis: { categories: <%= promiseTimes%>, title: 'Promise Times' },
            colorAxis: { min: <%= minToken%>, minColor: '#FFFFFF', maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] },
            legend: { align: 'right', layout: 'vertical', margin: 0, verticalAlign: 'top', y: 25, symbolHeight: 280 },
            tooltip: { formatter: function () {
                return 'Volume: ' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] 
                    + '<br>PromiseTime: ' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y]
                    + '<br>Profit: ' + this.point.value; } },
            series: [{ name: 'Profit', borderWidth: 1,
                data: <%= tokens%>}]
        });
        alert("heatmap refreshed!");

    }
</script>  
<script>
    <!-- var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer'); -->
</script> 
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <div id="divHeader" >
            <table>
                <tr><th><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Global Supply Network Division"></asp:Label></th>
                    <td rowspan="2"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ASCIcon.jpg" Height="55px" Width="55px" /></td></tr>
            <tr><th><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Assurance of Supply Center"></asp:Label></th></tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtPnlMenu" runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr><th class="thRight"><asp:Label ID="lblModel" runat="server" Text="Model" CssClass="lblParams"></asp:Label></th><td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddProducts" runat="server" OnTextChanged="ddProducts_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="ddl"></asp:DropDownList></td></tr>    
                    <tr><th class="thRight"><asp:Label ID="lblVolume" runat="server" Text="Volume" CssClass="lblParams"></asp:Label></th><td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddVolume" runat="server" CssClass="ddl"></asp:DropDownList></td></tr>
                    <tr><th class="thRight"><asp:Label ID="lblPromiseTime" runat="server" Text="PromiseTime" CssClass="lblParams"></asp:Label></th><td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddPromiseTime" runat="server" CssClass="ddl"></asp:DropDownList></td></tr>
                    <tr><th class="thRight"><asp:Label ID="lblWeighted" runat="server" Text="Res Weighted" CssClass="lblParams" ToolTip="Resilience Weighted"></asp:Label></th><td>
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="optWeighted" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="RWP" CssClass="optButton" /><asp:RadioButton ID="optNotWeighted" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="RWP" CssClass="optButton" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddProducts" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <div id="divContent">
            <ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer" runat="server" Width="90%">  
                <ajax:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Surfaces">  
                    <ContentTemplate>  
                        <div id="divHeatMap">Heatmap
                            <div id="container" style="height: 280px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divResilenceMap">Resilience Map</div>
                        <div id="divUsage">Usage Charts</div>
                    </ContentTemplate>  
                </ajax:TabPanel>  
                <ajax:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="Financial">   
                    <ContentTemplate>  
                        <div id="divWorldMap">Worldmap</div>
                        <div id="divWaterfall">Waterfall Charts</div> 
                    </ContentTemplate>  
                </ajax:TabPanel>  
                <ajax:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="Lanes">  
                    <ContentTemplate>  
                        <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>

                    </ContentTemplate>  
                </ajax:TabPanel>  
            </ajax:TabContainer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    Db db = new Db();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack == true)
        { 
            selProducts();
        }
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "selProduct", "refreshHeatMap();", true);
    }


    public void selProducts()
    {
        DataTable dt = db.selProducts();
        ddProducts.DataSource = dt;
        ddProducts.DataTextField = "Product";
        ddProducts.DataValueField = "Product";
        ddProducts.DataBind();
        ddProducts.SelectedIndex = 0;
        selVolumesAndPromiseTimes(ddProducts.Text);
    }


    protected void ddProducts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selVolumesAndPromiseTimes(ddProducts.Text);
    }

    private void selVolumesAndPromiseTimes(string prd)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        if (db.selVolumesAndPromiseTimes(prd, ref ds) == false)
        {
            DataTable dtVol = ds.Tables["Volumes"];
            ddVolume.DataSource = dtVol;
            ddVolume.DataTextField = "Volume";
            ddVolume.DataValueField = "Volume";
            ddVolume.DataBind();

            List<int> _lVol = new List<int>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dtVol.Rows)
            {
                _lVol.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["Volume"]));
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer jss1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            volumes = jss1.Serialize(_lVol); //this make your list in jSON format like [88,99,10]

            DataTable dtPromise = ds.Tables["PromiseTimes"];
            ddPromiseTime.DataSource = dtPromise;
            ddPromiseTime.DataTextField = "PromiseTime";
            ddPromiseTime.DataValueField = "PromiseTime";
            ddPromiseTime.DataBind();

            List<int> _lPT = new List<int>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dtPromise.Rows)
            {
                _lPT.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["PromiseTime"]));
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer jss2 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            promiseTimes = jss2.Serialize(_lPT);

            DataTable dtProfits = ds.Tables["Profits"];

            List<List<int>> _tokens = new List<List<int>>();
            Int32 minTkn = 999999; //start with a big number
            foreach (DataRow row in dtProfits.Rows)
            {
                List<int> _lPft = new List<int>();
                _lPft.Add(_lVol.IndexOf(Convert.ToInt32(row["Volume"])));
                _lPft.Add(_lPT.IndexOf(Convert.ToInt32(row["PromiseTime"])));
                Int32 mPft = Convert.ToInt32(row["Profit"]);
                if (mPft < minTkn) { minTkn = mPft; }
                _lPft.Add(mPft);
                _tokens.Add(_lPft);
            }
            minToken = minTkn;
            JavaScriptSerializer jss3 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            tokens = jss2.Serialize(_tokens);

            //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "selProduct", "refreshHeatMap()", true);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "selProduct", "refreshHeatMap();", true);

        }
    }

    public string volumes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string promiseTimes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string tokens
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Int32 minToken
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest being more specific about the points in your code that are relevant. Peoples interest in reading hundreds of lines are limited.

Comment: To get data from the backend you should consider using AJAX. That parts of the code: `<%= tokens%>` are assigned only once, when page is visited/loaded (won't change in real time..).